# Why does this evaluate to undefined in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Why does the final line evaluate to undefined in JavaScript?

```
function Boat() {}

var myBoat = new Boat();

console.log(Boat.prototype); //Boat(){}

console.log(myBoat.__proto__); //Boat(){}

console.log(myBoat.__proto__.prototype); //undefined - why is this not Boat(){}
```

Comment: Have you noticed that `myBoat.prototype` is also `undefined`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `__proto__` property refers to the prototype of the instance's constructor. So your second example logs exactly the same object as the first:

```
Boat.prototype === myBoat.__proto__;
```

The prototype of `Boat.prototype` is `undefined` since `Boat.prototype` is not a function. In fact, it's effectively an instance of `Object` so:

```
Boat.prototype.__proto__ === Object.prototype;
```

And by extension:

```
myBoat.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype;
```

---

Side note - use of the `__proto__` property is deprecated. [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) should be used instead where possible:

```
Boat.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf(myBoat); // Equivalent to 1st example
```

Comment: @cookiemonster - It refers to the internal `[[Prototype]]` property of an object, which in this case is the prototype of the constructor (as shown by `myBoat.__proto__ === Boat.prototype`.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `myBoat.__proto__` is not a function, but an object, and therefore it does not containt the `prototype` property. You could try this:

```
console.log(myBoat.__proto__.constructor.prototype);
```

Answer (score 1):

Every object has a prototype, but the `prototype` property is available only for functions or function objects. Otherwise the prototype for an object can be accessed using the `__proto__` identifier in all browsers except IE.

If `__proto__` is not available, the prototype can be obtained from the constructor property like this `myBoat.constructor.prototype`